# angular 2+ allocate data from activated route params

Tags: angular, angular-routing

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  user: {id: number, name: string};

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.user = {
    //   id: this.route.snapshot.params.id,
    //   name: this.route.snapshot.params.name
    // }
    this.user.id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    this.user.name = this.route.snapshot.params.name;
  }

}
```

Here is the code. And I am trying to allocate some data to the user object. And then I tried to allocate data to it by method-1:

```
// method-1
    this.user.id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    this.user.name = this.route.snapshot.params.name;
```

And it did not work actually. But then I tried another method-2 which seems like very similar to the method-1 and it worked. I wonder what the differences between these 2 methods are.

```
   // method-2
     this.user = {
       id: this.route.snapshot.params.id,
       name: this.route.snapshot.params.name
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration that you have used is wrong for method-1.
Because that will create blue-print of user object and in that way it is not possible to store data in object using method-1.

Here is the solution:

```
user:any = {id: '', name: ''};
```

If you define user object this way, your both the method-1 and method-2 will works fine.